How can I carry user login information from a landing page to the home page in React using Firebase as authentication?
I tried to add the user information (like email and photoURL) to an object but then I couldn't find a way to export it to the home page. I can access the user info locally but I can't use it in another page. I tried finding a way to use Global State but I couldn't figure it out and I don't know if there is a simpler way.
The entire idea of my project is to have a movie picker website where different users can select different movies to add to their "Watch Later" section therefore I wanted to implement profiles.
Don't mind my disgusting code.
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithPopup, signOut } from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth, provider } from '../firebaseConfig';
import { getFirestore, doc, setDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createGlobalState } from 'react-hooks-global-state';




const LandingPage = () => {

    const [email,setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password,setPassword] = useState('')
    const navigate = useNavigate();



    const handleSignIn = async() =>{

        try{
            await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email,password)
            setEmail('')
            setPassword('')
            const currentUser = auth.currentUser
            setGlobalState('email',currentUser.email)
            setGlobalState('pfpURL',currentUser.photoURL)
            // navigate(`/`)
        }catch(error){
            console.error(error)
        }


    }

    const signInWithGoogle = async() =>{
        try{
            await signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
            setEmail('')
            setPassword('')
            const currentUser = auth.currentUser
            setGlobalState('email',currentUser.email)
            setGlobalState('pfpURL',currentUser.photoURL)
            // const val = useGlobalState('email')
            console.log(globalEmail)
            // navigate(`/`)
        }catch(error){
            console.error(error)
        }

    } 

    const logout = async() =>{
        try{
            await signOut(auth)
            setEmail('')
            setPassword('')
        }catch(error){
            console.error(error)
        }

    }

    console.log(auth?.currentUser?.email)





    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <h1>Landing Page</h1>
                <hr />
                <div className="dropdown">
                    <button >Go</button>
                    <div className="menu">
                        <a href="/">Link 1</a>
                        <a href="/Watched">Link 2</a>
                        <a href="">Link 3</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
    
                <input type="text" 
                placeholder='Email...'
                value={email}
                onChange={(e)=>setEmail(e.target.value)}/>

                <br />
                <input type="password" 
                value={password}
                placeholder='Password...'
                onChange={(e)=>setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
                <br />

                <button onClick= {()=>handleSignIn()}>Sign in</button>
                <br />

                <button onClick={()=>signInWithGoogle()}>Sign In With Google</button>
                <button onClick={()=>logout()}>Logout</button>
                    
            </div>


        </div>
    );
};

export default LandingPage;


I'd suggest you to utilize react Context. It will be a HOC that is able to provide data and functions to children components. Create a state object in it to hold user data obtained from firebase, set this data from your Login component and use this data from any other component that is within the scope of that Context. Here is a good freecodecamp tutorial

i'm not supposed to add non-essential comments but i can't approve the comment for some reason. This worked thank you .
